# Скрипт работает не правильно load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

На сайте нужно создать свои модальные окна, я сделал это примерно так:

```
<a href="page.html" id="button">Открыть модальное окно</a>
```

При нажатии на ссылку выше, открывается данный блок:

```
<div id="div1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="div2">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.div2').load(this.href, function() {
        $('#div1').show();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Казалось все правильно работает. Но есть нюанс, который для меня стал проблемой. 
Таких ссылок с id button будет примерно 5-10 на странице, а скрипт открывает только одну ссылку, для других ссылок данный скрипт не срабатывает.

Посмотрите пожалуйста пример работы скрипта: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/eifpA35DNXEhER8N0OZR?p=preview)

Окно 1 загружает страницу page.html, но окно 2 просто открывается. В чем ошибка? 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте вместо идентификатора другой селектор, например, класс.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.